# Contexts not working after migration

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

I have a site with several contexts. When I migrated the site to a new server, they stopped working. The default context is the only one that works. I get a bunch of errors like this:

`[2011-06-12 12:53:19] (ERROR @ /index.php) [[++my_context_var]] is not a valid integer and may not be passed to makeUrl()`

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with your .htaccess file, missing alias domains or your context switching plugin.

- check your .htaccess got migrated [some FTP clients will ignore hidden files]
- ensure all the domain aliases [if any] got migrated
- add some debugging to your context switcher plugin

Let's see the source of your context switcher plugin.